# Hyperref not jumping to the appropriate location for memoir's subbottom

Tags: hyperref, captions, memoir, subcaption

I'm trying to utilize native Memoir `subbottom` command. However, I'm unable to make `hyperref` links jump "to the picture", rather than "to the caption". Only links to (a) and (d) work as desired.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\newsubfloat{figure} % allows to use "subbottom"

\begin{document}
This link jumps to the figure caption: \ref{fig:1}. 
% This one could be fixed with "\usepackage[all]{hypcap}", 
% but is it the correct approach?

This link jumps to the picture (the way I like): \ref{sf:1}. 

This link jumps to slightly-above-subcaption: \ref{sf:2}. 

This link jumps to slightly-above-subcaption: \subcaptionref{sf:3}, same as \ref{sf:3}.

This link jumps to the picture (the way I like): \ref{sf:4}.

This link jumps to slightly-above-subcaption: \ref{sf:5}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
% \hfill   % if uncommented, link to sf:1 jumps to incorrect vertical position too. Why?
\subbottom[Subfigure 1\label{sf:1}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\hfill
\subbottom[Subfigure 2\label{sf:2}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\hfill
\subbottom[\label{sf:3}Subfigure 3]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}
\\
\subbottom[Subfigure 4\label{sf:4}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\hfill
\subbottom[\label{sf:5}Subfigure 5]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\caption{Figure with five subfigures\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}        


\clearpage
This text is here to add more space for scrolling.

\end{document}
```

Here's the result I see (TexLive 2018, Windows 10):
[image: Click on link to sf:1 and to sf:2]

My example is similar to those provided in [the docs](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) (*Figure 10.19 in version v3.7g, 2018/04/04*). And it looks like the issue is present in the docs pdf itself.

Similar code, utilizing `subcaptionbox` works OK. And "*Where do hyperlinks jump?*" is nicely documented in the [subcaption package docs](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf). But it looks like using `subcaptionbox` with Memoir is discouraged - the following warning is generated:

> You are using the caption package with the memoir class. To prepare we
>   will now reset all captioning macros and configurations to kernel
>   defaults, and then let the caption package take over. Please remember
>   to use the caption package interfaces in order to configure your
>   captions.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there any other way to make links jump "to the picture", rather than using `caption` and `subcaption` packages?

Comment: Submitted an issue to `hypcap` maintainer: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/42

Comment: Note: there is nothing wrong in using the caption package and derived packages with memoir. The warning is just there to tell you that when you load the caption package with memoir, you can no longer use memoirs own caption configuration macros, they are ignored as `caption` has now taken over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more proper patch that does the right thing (move the refstepcoounter) into the formatting. It has been tested with `\subbottom`, `\contsubbottom`, `\subtop` and `\contsubtop` and the anchors seem to do the right thing

```
[sub optimal version removed]
```

---

Edit

This one seems simpler. We add the step counter at the start of the `\vtop`, this puts the anchor a little higher than the contents, which looks better. And it works with and *without* `hyperref`, the earlier version did not. I'll have a look at `\subcaption` as well.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% less typing     
\newcommand\mem@step@subcounter{%
  \refstepcounter{sub\@captype}\@contkeep%
}

\xpatchcmd{\@memsubbody}%
{\refstepcounter{sub\@captype}\@contkeep}% search pattern
{}% replacement
{\typeout{@memsubbody is patched}}%
{\typeout{@memsubbody is NOT patched}}%

\xpatchcmd{\@memcontsubbody}%
{\refstepcounter{sub\@captype}\@contkeep}% pattern
{}% replacement
{\typeout{@memcontsubbody is patched}}%
{\typeout{@memcontsubbody is NOT patched}}%

\xpatchcmd{\@memsubfloat}%
{\vtop\bgroup}% search pattern
{\vbox\bgroup\mem@step@subcounter}% replacement
{\typeout{@memsubfloat patch is ok}}%
{\typeout{@memsubfloat patch is NOT ok}}%


\makeatother
```

---

For `\subcaption`

```
\xpatchcmd{\subcaption}%
{\refstepcounter{sub\@captype}}% search pattern
{\H@refstepcounter{sub\@captype}}% replacement
{\typeout{subcaption second patch is ok}}%
{\typeout{subcaption second patch is NOT ok}}%
```

can be used under `hypcap`, just note that the link name will be wrong.

Comment: Great, thanks! I can confirm that this works for me. But it's a pity that `\subcaption` still behaves as before, though...

Comment: @Igor haven't gotten to that yet. Note that the above solution actually does not work generally, something strange happens if you remove hyperref, haven't figured that one out yet.

Comment: @Igor I've added a better patch for `\subbottom` and `\subtop`

Comment: @dalief Thanks! But `\subcaption` (from [rev5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/466515/5)) still behaves strange for me, see (c) [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/czmbmmtnqrrg).

Comment: @Igor if subcaption jumps anywhere it would be to the start of the entire figure. I'm guessing the other targets intervene (they are probably global). It might be an idea to simply switch to the caption and subcaption packages, the have much more features than what memoir can offer (and still be maintainable)

Comment: @Igor I think it would work if you only used one type in a single figure instead of testing all types in one

Comment: Yep, they both [do work OK](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tmsmvxsftxvx) if not mixed. And I do agree that mixing them is hardly a practical case - that was kind of synthetic test. (Their behavior is different - I'm not sure if it's good or bad. Probably good, cause it effectively allows to configure it the way you like.).

Comment: @Igor The problem here is "easy" to fix as long as the contents (image) is being handled as an argument. When it is just an item in an environment it is a different matter. Then we probably have to go with `hypcap` which redefines how `\caption` work (and makes assumptions on how it is implemented), even then it is not easy to handle.

Comment: It looks like the patch from the rev 5 of your answer got a side effect - [subfigures become top-aligned](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qdsxdqycrpyd). One [proposed](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/Russian-Phd-LaTeX-Dissertation-Template/issues/319#issuecomment-493527749) fix is to [replace `\vtop` with `\vbox`](https://www.overleaf.com/read/byqsrfgrnfwn). Do you that this should work OK? If so, could you please edit your answer?