# \centerlastline for captions in tabularray

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, memoir, tabularray

I’m trying to migrate to `tabularray` and I’m stuck with caption formatting.
I need the caption to be justified, *except* for the last line, which should be centered; if there is only one line, it should be centered. Also the caption tag should be flushed right on its own line.

I’m using `memoir` document class, so before I was following its manual and achieving what I need like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\SCTableFont}{\small} % 12pt
\newcommand{\SCTableLabelFont}{\SCTableFont\itshape}
\newcommand{\SCTableCaptionFont}{\SCTableFont\bfseries}

\setfloatadjustment{table}{
\captionnamefont{\hfill\SCTableLabelFont}
\captiontitlefont{\SCTableCaptionFont}
\captiondelim{}
\captionstyle[\centering\\]{\centerlastline\\} % <--- !!!
\SCTableFont
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [htbp]%
\caption{Not too long caption should be centered}%
\label{tbl:not-too-long}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
first & second \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [htbp]%
\caption{If a caption is long enough to not fit in a single line, it should be rendered as a block paragraph but with the last line centered. If a caption is long enough to not fit in a single line, it should be rendered as a block paragraph but with the last line centered.}%
\label{tbl:long}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
first & second \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\ref{tbl:not-too-long}, \ref{tbl:long}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `memoir` provides (1) `\captionstyle` with an optional argument, which is used exactly when the caption consists of a single line; and (2) `\centerlastline`, which does exactly what I need.

Now I’m trying to get the same result from `tabularray`, and I’m failing miserably:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\SCTableFont}{\small} % 12pt
\newcommand{\SCTableLabelFont}{\SCTableFont\itshape}
\newcommand{\SCTableCaptionFont}{\SCTableFont\bfseries}

\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{%
{\hfill % <--- \raggedleft does not work
\SCTableLabelFont
Table\hspace{0.25em}\thetable}%
\newline
{\centering % <--- does not work; \centerlastline does not work either
\SCTableCaptionFont
\InsertTblrText{caption}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [htbp]%
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Not too long caption should be centered},
  label = {tbl:not-too-long}
  ]{|X|X|}
\hline
first & second \\
\hline
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [htbp]%
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {If a caption is long enough to not fit in a single line, it should be rendered as a block paragraph but with the last line centered. If a caption is long enough to not fit in a single line, it should be rendered as a block paragraph but with the last line centered.},
  label = {tbl:long}
  ]{|X|X|}
\hline
first & second \\
\hline
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\ref{tbl:not-too-long}, \ref{tbl:long}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously there is some procedure here that I’m not getting. I was sure that I should use `\SetTblrStyle` for this; something along the lines of

```
\SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{halign=???}
```

except (1) `tabularray` provides only `l (left), c (center), r (right) or j (justify)` for this key, and (2) as far as I understand styles do not apply if you redefine the whole caption template (instead of its separate parts). (And in turn, I can’t redefine separate parts because writing `\DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{\newline}` does not work).

I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690847) and it made my hair stand on end, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the course of trying to solve this problem, I stumbled upon a very interesting [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524747#comment1336717_524747) by the author of the `memoir` class:

> I maintain memoir and regularly use caption with memoir as it has more
> features than what memoir will ever support out of the box.

...which instantly reminded me of Gaben [more or less recommending Unity instead of Source](https://www.pcgamesn.com/source-2-release-date).

So I bit the bullet and made the transition from built-in `memoir` captions to `caption`.

After that, integrating said `caption` into `tabularray` was straightforward:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{SCTableCaptionStyle}{%
font=small,% affecting the whole caption
labelfont=it,% affects the caption label and separator
textfont=bf,% only affects the caption text
labelsep=period,%
skip=2pt,%
position=above,%
parskip=0pt,%
indention=0cm%
}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{SCTableCaptionFormat}{\raggedleft#1\par\centerlast#3}

\captionsetup[table]{%
style=SCTableCaptionStyle,%
format=SCTableCaptionFormat%
}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628973

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { e } { TF }
\let\SCIfTokenListEmpty=\tl_if_empty:eTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{default}{%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \captionsetup{type=table}%
  \SCIfTokenListEmpty{\InsertTblrText{entry}}{%
    \caption{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
  }{%
    \caption[\InsertTblrText{entry}]{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
  }%
}


% While we're at it, let's make continuation/conclusion captions for longtblr too

\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead}{default}{%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \captionsetup{type=table,style=SCContTableCaptionStyle}%
  \caption[]{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
}

\DefTblrTemplate{lasthead}{default}{%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \captionsetup{type=table,style=SCConclTableCaptionStyle}%
  \caption[]{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
}

% Allows to avoid duplicate entries in the LoT.
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628900/628973#comment1572626_628973.
\SetTblrTemplate{caption-lot}{empty}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{SCTableContConclCaptionLabelFormat}{tbl. #2}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{SCTableContCaptionFormat}{\raggedleft Continuation of #1}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{SCTableConclCaptionFormat}{\raggedleft Conclusion of #1}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{SCContTableCaptionStyle}{
style=SCTableCaptionStyle,%
font+=it,
format=SCTableContCaptionFormat,%
labelformat=SCTableContConclCaptionLabelFormat%
}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{SCConclTableCaptionStyle}{
style=SCTableCaptionStyle,%
font+=it,
format=SCTableConclCaptionFormat,%
labelformat=SCTableContConclCaptionLabelFormat%
}

% Remove "Continued on next page" at table bottom
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot}{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [htbp]%
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Not too long caption should be centered},
  label = {tbl:not-too-long}
  ]{|X|X|}
\hline
first & second \\
\hline
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [htbp]%
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {If a caption is long enough to not fit in a single line, it should be rendered as a block paragraph but with the last line centered. If a caption is long enough to not fit in a single line, it should be rendered as a block paragraph but with the last line centered.},
  label = {tbl:long}
  ]{|X|X|}
\hline
first & second \\
\hline
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\ref{tbl:not-too-long}, \ref{tbl:long}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can’t help but think that for all the insane work that went into captions support in `tabularray` – all those `Template`s, `Style`s and `Theme`s – maybe following the footsteps of `memoir`’s author and just adding deep integration with the `caption` package would’ve been a better choice.